# strip characters from string ignoring html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, tinymce

I am using `tinyMCE` wysiwyg editor for textareas in one of my projects. I have been looking for a way to limit the characters entered by a user.

My requirements are:

- Do not let a user enter more than specified character limit. (so the method should be bound to keyDown / keyUp event).
- Make sure this works with copy / paste too (i.e. `ctrl+v` and right
  mouse click and `paste`).
- On copy / paste the behavior should be --> strip the excess characters from the `innerText` and set the content to the stripped text but still keep the `styles` that were applied to the original content.

I have had a look at the [`maxchars`](http://sourceforge.net/p/tinymce/plugins/127/) plugin but it just does not serve the purpose especially when it comes to the `copy / paste` functionality. I tried implementing custom methods to achieve the above mentioned requirements.

What I have already achieved is as follows:

---

**Prevent users from entering anymore characters once the character limit is reached.**

```
function preventExcessChars(editor, event) {
    var body = editor.getBody(),
        limit = editor.settings.charLimit,
        text = body.innerText || body.textContent,
        length = text.length;

    if (length >= limit && isCharacterKeyPress(event)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Once bound to the `keyDown` or `keyUp` event this works fine and does not allow a user to enter anymore characters once the character limit is reached. The problem with this is that it does not support `copy / paste` so a user can paste as many chars as he wants.

**Take care of `copy`/`paste`.**

In order to implement the `copy /paste` functionality I thought it would be good to use the `tinyMCE`'s `setContent` method to update the content. so i updated the above to:

```
function preventExcessChars(editor, event) {
    var body = editor.getBody(),
        limit = editor.settings.charLimit,
        text = body.innerText || body.textContent,
        length = text.length;

    if (length >= limit && isCharacterKeyPress(event)) {
        // update the content and use setContent to update the text area
        var new_content = text.substr(0, limit);
        editor.setContent(new_content);
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
    }   
}
```

This works pretty well. The problem with this is that it does not apply the styles from the original content to the new content as new content is `innerText` object.

---

Is there a way I can strip out characters from the `innerHTML` instead of `innerText` and avoid stripping any HTML tags included in the string ??

So for example say I have the following string:

```
 "<p>This is a <b>test</b>.</p><p>I have been <i>testing</i> this since morning.</p>";
```

the length of the `innerText` for the above string is `55` characters and say the limit is`50` chars. I want to strip out the last `5` characters from the above string so that the result is:

```
 "<p>This is a <b>test</b>.</p><p>I have been <i>testing</i> this since mor</p>"
```

If I do this using the above code (i.e. using `innerText`) the result I get is `This is a test. I have been testing this since mor`. How can I get the above result that includes the html tags ?

Comment: Just build yourself a little DOM tree, so that you can prune the text nodes.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but have you considered just using a character count that updates on keypress? A little bit like this comment control I'm typing in right now. This approach is better UX because it does two things: First, the user can see how much room they have left to type. Second, it allows the user to initially go WAY over the character limit, then go back and edit it/trim it down so that it fits. You shouldn't prevent the user from entering more characters, you just need to prevent them from submitting it. For the record, I did just that while writing this comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
function maxChars(str, max) {
  var tags = 0,
      sQuotes = 0,
      dQuotes = 0,
      char,
      count = 0,
      result = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; ++i) {
    char = str.charAt(i);
    switch(char) {
      case '<':
        if (!sQuotes && !dQuotes) {
          ++tags;
          result.push(char);
          continue;
        }
        break;
      case '>':
        if (!sQuotes && !dQuotes) {
          --tags;
          result.push(char);
          continue;
        }
        break;
      case "'":
        if (tags && !dQuotes)
          sQuotes = !sQuotes;
        break;
      case '"':
        if (tags && !sQuotes)
          dQuotes = !dQuotes;
        break;
    }
    if (tags) {
      result.push(char);
    } else {
      if (++count < max)
        result.push(char);
    }
  }
  return result.join('');
};

// Example
var text = "<p>This is a <b>test</b>.</p><p>I have been <i>testing</i> this since morning.</p>";
maxChars(text, 50);
// "<p>This is a <b>test</b>.</p><p>I have been <i>testing</i> this since mor</p>"
```